# Stata: Why aren't these two strings the same?

Tags: stata

I define two local variables, str1 and str2, containing strings with the same characters---the only difference is str2 has been broken into two lines. They both display the same string, but str2 is only of length 1 and hence is different from str1. Why is this the case?

```
local str1 "abc"
display "`str1'"
. abc
display strlen("`str1'")  // get string length
. 3

local str2 "a" ///
           "bc"
display "`str2'"
. abc
display strlen("`str2'")
. 1

display ("`str1'" == "`str2'")
. 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem lies not in breaking your string between two lines, but in breaking it into two parts. Consider

```
. local str3 "a" "bc"
. display "`str3'"
abc
. display strlen("`str3'")
1
```

A look at `help local` suggests that the syntax you attempted - giving two string constants for the macro - is not within the range of the documented syntax. Consider instead the syntax that allows an expression for the definition, and use it to concatenate the two strings.

```
. local str4 = "a" ///
>              + "bc"
. display "`str4'"
abc
. display strlen("`str4'")
3
```

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental here is that your definition of `str2` has the consequence, no doubt unintended, of including the middle double quotation marks in the local macro. It follows that you will get misleading results unless thereafter you delimit the macro by *compound* double quotation marks.

What is also crucial is that `display` has a presentation role as well as a reporting role and to some extent interprets what is fed to it. It's not always utterly literal therefore. In particular, it will strip delimiters, or what it thinks are delimiters, before displaying a string. Usually this is pure feature, but in your example it stops you seeing the consequences of your definition.

The puzzlement therefore centres on the fact that double quotation marks `" "` have two roles in Stata, as string delimiters and as literal characters.

```
. local str2 "a" ///
>            "bc"

. display "`str2'"
abc

. display `"`str2'"' 
a"            "bc

. display strlen("`str2'")
1

. display strlen(`"`str2'"')
17
```

Comment: It might also be worth noting that the results of `macro dir` display the macro with the middle double quotes and enclosed white space not stripped away. Further `strlen()` will (I believe) always return the length of the first of the two parts that were assigned to the local when assigned this way, further illustrating why this happens.